# Eliminación de una cadena de una columna de un marco de datos

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Tengo la columna de una dataframe donde me gustaria quitarle las '! ':

```
>>>shops['shop_name_en'].head()

0          ! Yakutsk Ordzhonikidze, 56 francs 
1    ! Yakutsk shopping center "Central" Fran 
2               Adygea shopping center "Mega" 
3             Balashiha TRK "October-Kinomir" 
4       Volzhsky shopping center "Volga Mall"
```

Entonces itenté:

```
>>>shops.replace({'shop_name_en': r'^! $'}, {'shop_name_en': ''}, regex=True)
```

Pero no le quiten:

```
shop_name   shop_id city    shop_name_en
0   !Якутск Орджоникидзе, 56 фран   57  !   ! Yakutsk Ordzhonikidze, 56 francs
1   !Якутск ТЦ "Центральный" фран   58  !   ! Yakutsk shopping center "Central" Fran
2   Адыгея ТЦ "Мега"    2   Adygea  Adygea shopping center "Mega"
3   Балашиха ТРК "Октябрь-Киномир"  3   Balashiha   Balashiha TRK "October-Kinomir"
4   Волжский ТЦ "Волга Молл"    4   Volzhsky    Volzhsky shopping center "Volga Mall"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu expresión regular sobra el `$`, pues el dólar representa el final de la cadena, por lo que tu expresión encajaría sólo con cadenas que sean púramente `"! "` y no sólo que comiencen por `"! "` como pretendes.

Por tanto una solución es simplemente:

```
shops.replace({'shop_name_en': r'^! '}, {'shop_name_en': ''}, regex=True)
```

Otra opción más simple es en lugar de aplicar `.replace()` sobre el dataframe completo (lo que te obliga a pasar diccionarios con los nombres de las columnas), aplicar `.replace()` sólo sobre la columna en cuestión, así:

```
shops.shop_name_en = shops.shop_name_en.replace(r'^! ', '', regex=True)
print(shops)
```

---

```
                        shop_name  ...                            shop_name_en
0   !Якутск Орджоникидзе, 56 фран  ...        Yakutsk Ordzhonikidze, 56 francs
1   !Якутск ТЦ "Центральный" фран  ...  Yakutsk shopping center "Central" Fran
2                Адыгея ТЦ "Мега"  ...           Adygea shopping center "Mega"
3  Балашиха ТРК "Октябрь-Киномир"  ...         Balashiha TRK "October-Kinomir"
4        Волжский ТЦ "Волга Молл"  ...   Volzhsky shopping center "Volga Mall"
```